# Form Submission - false positive

Tags: javascript, office-365, custom-form, html

I have a custom NewForm (not infopath) on O365 SharePoint that is failing to submit to the backend list.  I have a redirect on it to a thank you page and some custom validation using the PreSaveAction javascript mathod.  The form appears to be saving and users are redirected after the Submit button is clicked, but no row in the list is created, nor is any automated email flying.

Anyone else have experience like this?  The amount of data sending up to the list is almost trivial, though there is custom JS and HTML in the layout.  Failure seems to be inconsistent as tests with the same info will fail or succeed seemingly at random.

Comment: Can you please add the code you are using to insert the item in list?

Comment: Thanks @Ganesh, I am just using the OOTB __commit method with the __redirect option:  `<input type="button" id="btnOk" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" value="Submit" onclick="javascript: if(!PreSaveItem()) return false;{ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={/sites/MySite/SitePages/My%20Requests.aspx}')}" />`